# What is the best way to add javascript to Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have very strange problem. I was create a module which add javascript code to head and the codeis display. This is Merchant Review from Google. When client payed for product then this code should display a popup with question. I create a if conditions which display this code only after payment module. But nothing is displayed. Maybe my problem is in the way how I do it ?

```
 public function hookDisplayHeader() {
        if (Tools::getValue('id_order') != 0) {
            //$this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn');

            $date = new DateTime('+3 day');
            $estimated_delivery_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $merchantreviews_merchant_id = Configuration::get('PSOFT_MERCHANTREVIEWS_ID');
            $merchantreviews_order_id = (int) Tools::getValue('id_order');
            $merchantreviews_email = $this->context->customer->email;
            $merchantreviews_country = $this->context->country->iso_code;



            return '<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn"
  async defer>
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.renderOptIn = function () {
window.gapi.load("surveyoptin", function () {
                window.gapi.surveyoptin.render({
                "merchant_id": "' . $merchantreviews_merchant_id . '",
                            "order_id": "' . $merchantreviews_order_id . '",
                            "email": "' . $merchantreviews_email . '",
                            "delivery_country": "' . $merchantreviews_country . '",
                            "estimated_delivery_date": "' . $estimated_delivery_date . '",
                            "opt_in_style": "CENTER_DIALOG"
                    });
                });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.___gcfg = {
            lang: "pl"
        };
    </script>
    ';
        }
    }
```

And how it is look in source code, html.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn"
  async defer>
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.renderOptIn = function () {
window.gapi.load("surveyoptin", function () {
                window.gapi.surveyoptin.render({
                "merchant_id": "120321173",
                            "order_id": "32",
                            "email": "pub@prestashop.com",
                            "delivery_country": "PL",
                            "estimated_delivery_date": "2018-02-26",
                            "opt_in_style": "CENTER_DIALOG"
                    });
                });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.___gcfg = {
            lang: "pl"
        };
```

Thanks for any help.

--edit
Now in console I see this:

```
Content Security Policy: Ignorowanie „'unsafe-inline'” w script-src: określono „strict-dynamic”
Content Security Policy: Ignorowanie „https:” w script-src: określono „strict-dynamic”
Content Security Policy: Ignorowanie „http:” w script-src: określono „strict-dynamic”
```

Comment: is there any error on the browser console log?

Comment: The code is executed? Insert a `console.log()` inside

Comment: It is. I edit my post. Please check it again.